# SQL arithmetic overflow caused by negative numbers in part of formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

[Problem illustrated here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUi6K.jpg)

A computed value is causing an arithmetic overflow due to some of the computations resulting in negative numbers in the update statement, but the ultimate value should be consistent with the declared column.  Help please!

Comment: Please ignore my typo in the illustration of the problem.   The formula is:  Round((ExpMth - (CurrMth + .05) + 12 * (ExpYr - CurrYr)) / ((ExpMth - EffMth) + 12 * (Expr - EffYr)),6,1)

Comment: not what is shown:  Round((ExpMth - (CurrMth + .05) + 12 * (ExpYr - CurrYr)) / ((ExpMth - EffMth) + 12 * (Expr - EffYr)),7,1)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sorry... MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Numerics can store negative values, so that would not appear to be your problem.

Comment: You have to change your data types into a datatype appropriate for your results.  You have to do this data type change before you do the calculation.  Your data type will change with the Sql engine and version you are using but the issue remains the same.  Also have to insure you are not dividing by zero.

Comment: if there wasn't a problem, it wouldn't be throwing an error.  and the formula WORKS when all values compute to POSITIVE numbers.  this issue only started when a scenario with NEGATIVE numbers resulted.  if you don't comprehend something, don't comment.

Comment: @MT Head - I have tried some of that without success, was hoping for more detail.  there is no dividing by zero happening that's why I included the illustration to show the interim values.  But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: People comment to try to help and get greater clarity.  If your problem is only with negative numbers then I stand by my answer.  Your problem is likely with your data types.  Isolate to where you have an error, a single row.  Then change the data types before you do the calculation to a data type that supports the answer you calculated on that particular row.  I think you may be having as much difficulty understanding my answer as I did understanding your question.

Comment: @MT Head - my first comment was directed at Gordon because the comment "Your question makes no sense" isn't helpful and just wasn't true.  I understand your suggestion, it is the execution of such in a stored procedure that I am working on.  I am modifying someone else's code.  I was trying to avoid adding an interim step and hoping someone who knows sql/stored procedures would have an efficient way to wrap that data type conversion into the existing update.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I will leave it with research the data types you are using in your calculations.  I think you are thinking that the "target table" data types are what is being used in the calculations.  You need to change your data types before doing the calculations.  I think you don't understand my answer over it does not make sense.  Identify what data types each of your variables are in your calculation.

Comment: I was originally trying to set the data types at a higher level.  I wasn't expecting the month columns to behave differently from the year columns when it came to the calculation.  All is well now. Your suggestion did get me thinking I had to go to the lowest level - individual values in the calculation instead of the sums on each side of the divide.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Had to wrap each of the month columns with the cast function to get it to work.

Update @RptTable
   SET EarningFactor = ROUND((ExpMth - (CurrMth + 0.5) + 12 * (ExpYr - CurrYr)) / ((cast(ExpMth as numeric) - cast(EffMth as numeric)) + 12 * (ExpYr - EffYr)),6,1)

Comment: Glad you got it. I'm trying to figure out your equation still